# postegreSQL inserting query using node js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express

I have this code on index.js in which i connect to a postgreSQL database and execute a query but it keeps telling me: column "Jhonny" does not exist.
Here is my code:

```
const {Client} = require ('pg');

    const client = new Client({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'postgres',
        database: 'React',
        password: '01021997',
        port: 5432,
    })
    client.connect();
    client.query('INSERT INTO movies (moviename, review) VALUES ("Jhonny", "no 
    review");', (err, res)=>{
        if(!err){
            console.log('insert done');
        }else{
            console.log(err.message);
        }
        client.end;
    })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the query should be in the following way:

```
client.query(`INSERT INTO "movies" ("moviename", "review") VALUES ('Jhonny', 
'no review');`
```

the column names and the table name should be between ("") and the values should be between ('').